# Display axis units in numerical order in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am creating charts in **Matplotlib** that match dates (year only!) with publication names.

To set the **axis ticks**, I am currently using:

`plt.xticks(dates_new, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')`

This creates a graph that shows all publication years as they come out of my original, unsorted JSON file, not in chronological order.

I tried using `datetime`, but because I have no month/day values, there is an error notification.

After all, it's fine if the years are treated as mere integers --- I just need the axis values in **numerical order**.

Is there an easy way to achieve this in Matplotlib, or do I need to install additional packages like Seaborn?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is unclear whether `dates_new` is a list of strings, a numpy array, a column from a dataframe or maybe something else. Do they contain every year maximum once?  You could sort them with `plt.xticks(sorted(dates_new), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')` in case they are strings all with the same length.

Comment: ´dates_new´ is a list of strings in the YYYY format. They occur more than once, which is why I have chosen a scatter plot. Showing each year just once with several dots on the y axis is working fine. I will try the ´sorted´ function.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!